# How to simplify JS variables and getting `<input>`s by class, then sum their values?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I have many `<input>`s like this:

```
<input class="BUBU-1">
<input class="BUBU-2">
...
<input class="BUBU-1000">
```

how can I make variables similar to these:

```
var NEW1 = document.get...(" BUBU-1 ");
// ...
var NEW1000 = document.get...(" BUBU-1000 ");
```

but instead something like these (if it’s possible):

```
var SMTH = 1..1000;
var NEW[SMTH] = document.get...(" BUBU-[SMTH] ");
```

And then sum them, like `NEW1 + NEW2 + ... + NEW1000`, but with some function, which says *“take all `NEW[SMTH]` and sum them”*.

Comment: You probably want to write a loop which stores the input elements in an array. Then you can access them by their index. Is that what you mean? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Add a common class name to them all. Then the whole collection can be retrieved with one query selector

Comment: Give your inputs the same class name then use `document.querySelectorAll('your-classname')`. After that do what Ethan Rogers referenced.

Comment: Thanks, adding the same class can't help, cause every input has it's own value and there is another function and another group of buttons, which separately must get their values.

Comment: They can still have each their own value, although they have the same classname. Classname is for CSS.

Comment: *UPD, https://jsfiddle.net/uzadw5xm/54/ - - Fiddle demo, clicking on red squares, code works correctly, but it's going to grow, with 500+ elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get a single element like this:

```
let n = 1;

document.querySelector(".BUBU-" + n); // This yields `<input class="BUBU-1">`.
```

You can take the sum of their values, by building an array of numbers first, [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) them to the numeric values of their inputs of their selectors, then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them to a sum:

```
const sum = Array.from({
    length: 1000
  }, (_, index) => Number(document.querySelector(".BUBU-" + (index + 1)).value))
    .reduce((result, value) => result + value, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

If you want to remove empty or non-numeric fields before calculating the sum, use `.filter((value) => !isNaN(value))` before the `.reduce` line; this [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) [`NaN` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

If you want just an array of the numeric values, remove the `reduce` step. If you want the values as strings, rather than numbers, remove the `Number` call. If you want just the elements, rather than their values, use just `document.querySelector(".BUBU-" + (index + 1))`.

---

If all `<input>`s are all children of a *parent element*, e.g. a `<div id="allInputs">`, selecting and summing them becomes easier:

```
const sum = Array.from(document.querySelector("#allInputs input"), ({value}) => Number(value))
  .reduce((result, value) => result + value, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

---

If your `<input>`s should only contain numbers, consider giving them the [`type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) attribute. Then, you can also use something like `Array.from(document.querySelector("#allInputs input"), ({valueAsNumber: number}) => number)`, etc.

---

Seeing your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzadw5xm/51), make sure that your selectors are correct. `.BUBU-1` selects elements with `class="BUBU-1"`, `#BUBU-1` selects the (first) element with `id="BUBU-1"`.

If you want to listen to `change` events, consider using event delegation:

In vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.body.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  if(e.target.matches("input")){
    // Calculate sum, etc.
  }
});
```

In jQuery:

```
$("body").on("change", "input", function(e){
  // Calculate sum, etc.
});
```

As your JSFiddle appears to be more complex than your question, but you just asked about summing input fields with class names of a common pattern, if you do have a question about *a more complex problem*, consider asking a new question.

Comment: *#BUBU-1 selects elements with id="BUBU-1"* is slightly incorrect. `#BUBU-1` selects the **first** element with `id="BUBU-1"` (even if the HTML was invalid and there were more than one).

Comment: In jQuery, isn't the way to bind to multiple events `$("body").on("change input", function(e){`? I used to think the second parameter is for event delegation selector.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were actually not trying to bind to `input` event, but using "input" 2nd parameter exactly as a delegate selector. I'd suggest to use `[class^=BUBU-]` instead.

Comment: @connexo Yes, this is event delegation. It’s supposed to match `<input>` elements (I’m not sure which elements exactly the OP wants to listen to). This probably has nothing to do with calculating sums; it just shows how to use event delegation, since the OP used `$(` _lots of IDs_ `).change(function(e){`…`})`. Regarding the `[class*=BUBU-]` selector: this might also work here, but it’d also match elements with class names that don’t _start_ with `BUBU-`, but have that substring somewhere in the middle as well.

Comment: As long as OP isn't adding inputs dynamically, `$('[class^=BUBU-]').on('input', sum)` should be alot better performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you are correct. For comparing with the start of an attribute value it has to be `^`, not `*`.

Comment: @connexo Sure, `[class^=BUBU-]` works, too, but if it’s something like `class="BUBU BUBU-1"`, it doesn’t.

Answer (score 3):

1. Put all input elements in a NodeList using `document.querySelectorAll('[class^=BUBU-]');` and make that an array using array destructuring operator `...` (NodeList is an array-like structure, so it can be transformed to an array easily which allows to use methods available for Arrays on it, see step 2). (`[class^=BUBU-]` matches all elements that have a `class` attribute starting with `BUBU-`).
2. Use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to accumulate the values. Remember the values are always strings on inputs, so convert them to `Number` before adding.

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class^=BUBU-]')]

function sum(collection) {
  return collection.reduce((acc,val) => { return acc+Number(val.value) }, 0)
}

console.log(sum(inputs));
```

```html
<input class="BUBU-1" value="1">
<input class="BUBU-2" value="2">
...
<input class="BUBU-1000" value="1000">
```

Seeing that in your JSFiddle you're using `id` instead of `class`, simply adjust the selector to `document.querySelectorAll('[id^=BUBU-]'`)`.